# Capture a screenshot of HTML content using a WebBrowser control

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, multithreading, screenshot, webbrowser-control

I am using ASP.NET MVC with Entity Framework version 4.5.1.

I am trying to capture a screenshot of HTML content, including some  images, using a WebBrowser control in a separate thread.

I am  experiencing inconsistency in capturing images where some images appear correctly in the screenshot while others do not.

This is my code:

```
Thread thread = new Thread(() =>
                    {
                        using (var browser = new WebBrowser())
                        {
                            // Navigate to a blank page
                            browser.Navigate("about:blank");

                            // Wait for the WebBrowser control to finish loading
                            while (browser.ReadyState != WebBrowserReadyState.Complete)
                            {
                                Application.DoEvents();
                            }

                            // Inject the HTML content into the WebBrowser control
                            browser.Document.OpenNew(true);
                            browser.Document.Write(jobOrderHttml);

                            // Wait for all images to load
                            while (browser.Document.Body.All.Cast<HtmlElement>().Any(e => e.TagName.ToLower() == "img"
                            && !((bool)e.DomElement.GetType().GetProperty("complete").GetValue(e.DomElement))))
                            {
                                Application.DoEvents();
                            }

                            // Wait for the content to render
                            while (browser.ReadyState != WebBrowserReadyState.Complete)
                            {
                                Application.DoEvents();
                            }

                            // Set the size of the WebBrowser control to fit the content
                            browser.Width = browser.Document.Body.ScrollRectangle.Width;
                            browser.Height = browser.Document.Body.ScrollRectangle.Height;

                            // Ensure all content is visible by scrolling to the top
                            browser.Document.Window.ScrollTo(0, 0);

                            // Create a bitmap to capture the screenshot of the entire content
                            Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap(browser.Width, browser.Height);
                            browser.DrawToBitmap(bitmap, new Rectangle(0, 0, browser.Width, browser.Height));

                            // Save the bitmap as an image
                            string outputPath = JobOrdersPath + TicketJobOrderId + ".jpg";
                            bitmap.Save(outputPath, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png);

                            // Open the image file with the default image viewer
                            //System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(outputPath);
                        }
                    });
```

I am sure the path of images is correct because all images located in the same path.

Also I am trying to wait until all images is loaded.

The loop to wait for all images to load is always true so it does not work for me.

I have been stuck at this point for more than a week - any help please?